# Search Bar in Javascript - Partially Match Strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Trying to create a search bar for users that can type in a query which will then search through my JSON file to retrieve the proper contents.

Examples:

```
1-  User input: "15 inch touchscreen"
    Match with: "15-inch", "15", "Touchmonitor", "1537L", "Stand for 1501L-1601L"

2-  User input: "3243 ids"
    Match with: "3243L", "IDS"
```

Basically going for a full blown search function - so obviously speed will be a factor.

**Questions:**

1. Is there anyway to handle partial matches like that in Javascript or
   jQuery?
2. Would it be faster to load all products client side on page load and
   then search through them later, or search the JSON file at the time
   of the query?

Dealing with around a 5000 line JSON file so about 200KB

Comment: It would probably be better to use a database and not flat files, Elasticsearch comes to mind

Comment: Anyway -> **http://jsfiddle.net/sepyec33/**

Comment: @adeneo not really sure if that's an option. I am taking product data from an excel sheet price list and converting it to JSON. Then I would create a script to load the page contents from JSON. Need to make this a cookie cutter method so I can just take other price lists, convert to JSON and then point to it. This isn't for our website catalog - that is already on a database. This is more for the ability to create unique customer websites from a different set of information.

Comment: @adeneo one issue with the fiddle is that I would also like to match `touchscreen` with `touchmonitor` - but unsure of how easy that would be.  Would need to have a threshold for how many characters to partially match.

Comment: @Adjit characters to partially match could lead to undesired results, would be better to have a synonym system, so that touchscreen  matches itself and touchmonitor

Comment: Search is complicated, especially when you start wanting partial matches etc. Some of the worlds biggest companies have spent billions on figuring things like that out, and there are open souce projects and databases available that has this built in. Doing it with a few lines of javascript probably isn't a very good option for good consistent results.

Comment: @adeneo right - I don't need it to be super consistent, just need it to be able to find the product. Will most likely implement a combination of your search function and Juvian's idea of a synonym system. Because your search covers about 95% of the searches I need. Just need to cover that other 5%

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing your code.
The preferred way is to make the heavy calculations and logic on the server side - In case your data and logic is expected to grow in size and complexity.
So I'd definately suggest to look into a product like elastic: https://www.elastic.co/
However, if that file is constant (not expected to grow) you could definately implement that using plain javascript on the client.